# How to get types for node.js imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

When using node.js with express, you start your code with this -

```
import express = require('express')
const app = express()
```

now, if I wish to pass the variable app as a parameter, while using typescript, what would be the right type to associate it with?

I've ran this command -

```
 npm install --save-dev @types/express
```

So I assume I have the types locally, but i'm not sure how to import it into my file and rely on it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it by looking at this tutorial code sample - https://github.com/mwanago/express-typescript/blob/master/src/app.ts

The answer is - use `express.Application` as the type

Answer (score 3):

You can import express in typescript by doing

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
```

Now if you wish to set a type to `app`, you need to import a named export from express, which can be done by

```
import express, { Express } from 'express';

let app: Express;
app = express();
```

Also for this to function properly, make sure your `tsconfig.json` looks something like

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```